# Standard Error: multiplied or divided by SD?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I'm relearning stats after a number of years of non-use, and I have a great textbook I'm using which defines the SE as the square root of the number of draws from a box multiplied by the standard deviation of the number of members (n) of that box.

Yet everywhere I see SE defined as the standard deviation *divided* by the square root of n.

Can someone help me understand this discrepancy? Thank you!

Comment: **Note:** SE here means *standard error*.  SD means *standard deviation*.

Comment: I suspect that one is the SE based on the entire population whereas the other SE is based on one individual. That is: $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$times SD.

Comment: What I was able to learn is that the first represents the SE of the sum of numbers drawn with replacement from a box, and the second - with the square root of n in the denominator - is the SE of the average of all the draws. Is this correct?